# Переменные в классе ооп

Tags: php, ооп

есть класс и в нём есть

```
        protected $_host, $_login, $_password, $_port;
function __construct($config = array()) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $componentParams = $app->getParams('com_test');
    $this->_host = $componentParams->get('host');
    $this->_login = $componentParams->get('login');
    $this->_password = $componentParams->get('password');
    $this->_port = $componentParams->get('port');
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

Далее пишу функцию

```
private static function Conetc() {
    var_dump($this->_host); //Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
}
```

Вопрос как всё же объявить переменные что бы было видно их и в функциях....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 2):

Вы объявили функцию `Conetc` как статическую функцию.

```
private static function Conetc() 
        ^^^^^^
```

Она вызывается безотносительно объекта класса, поэтому не имеет доступа к нестатическим переменным класса.

Либо объявите функцию как нестатическую, либо передавайте ей в качестве аргумента объект класса.

Comment: 1) написал private function Coonet() {
        var_dump($this->_host);
} //Strict Standards: Non-static method и та же ошибка... 
2) что значит "либо передавайте ей в качестве аргумента объект класса."

Comment: @Олег Анатольевич Косарев  Это у вас определение класса, не так ли? Вы собираетесь создавать объекты этого класса.  Вот функция в качестве аргумента должна принимать объекты этого класса.

Comment: Верно эта класс... то есть Вы предлогаете писать 
Conetc($this->_host) я правильно понял?

Comment: @Олег Анатольевич Косарев  Я думаю, что не должно быть той же самый ошибки, если вы уберете ключевое слово static.

Comment: @Олег Анатольевич Косарев Я предлагаю убрать ключевое слово static.

Comment: Я вить писал private function Coonet() { var_dump($this->_host); } //Strict Standards: Non-static method и //Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in 
Или у функций у которых написано self::Conetc() тоже убирать static ?

Comment: @ОлегАнатольевичКосарев Все уже написано в моем ответе. Где в вашем примере кода присутствует self::Conetc? Сделайте так, как я указал и почитайте, наконец, документацию, на которую вам дали ссылку в комментарии к вашему вопросу. это займет минут 5.